# Desktop install: Separate home partition (LVM on LUKS) without using terminal

Tags: system-installation, home-directory, lvm, luks, ubiquity

How can I install Ubuntu desktop ≥16.04.1 with these options (LVM on LUKS):

[image: LVM on LUKS]

but with a separate home LV in the LUKS volume **without using a terminal**?

I can do this with the Ubuntu Server installer menus, but I can't in the desktop installer...

Comment: @George You'll have to be more explicit—that's not enough information for me to understand your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GUI installer supports that. But you can still do it without terminal just in more steps.

First install with these default settings.

Then resize your LVM Logical volume containing root file system. This step has to be done from live CD. KVPM can be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 live cd or alternatively you can use KDE Partition Manager 3.0. Here I'll focus on KDE Partition Manager since I'm more familiar with it because I'm it's maintainer and main developer. Probably the easiest way for you to obatain it is to download Neon Live CD. Boot it.

Then go to Menu->Applications->System->Software Center (Discover) and search for Partition Manager and then install KDE Partition Manager. Then click launch.

In KDE Partition Manager you will see your encrypted LUKS partition. Right click on it and click decrypt. Enter your passprase to open the volume. Then rescan your disks (either from menu or F5). Now you should be able to see new device corresponding to LVM volume group. Click on it. There you'll see your root file system. Resize it to free up space for your home partition. Create a new partition for your home in the freed space (you can leave it as default ext4). Now you need to mount both your root file system and home file system. One way to do it is open dolphin and on your left panel you should be able to see those devices. Or from system tray device notifier... Once you have mounted both partitions, move the contents of your home folder into the newly created home partition. Make sure you don't create extra home folder in that partition, it should be the contents of home folder.

You need to add that new home partition to fstab file but your normal user does not have permissions to do that. One way to avoid terminal is go to Software center again, install Krusader, then go to Menu->Applications->System->Krusader (root mode). Find fstab file you want to edit in your mounted rootfs/etc/. By the way, krusader can also be used in the previous step to copy your home folder to new partition.

Instruction how to edit fstab are https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab but basically you can copy entry for your rootfs, change the path at the beginning to point to your home lvm lv (you can see that path in KDE Partition Manager) and change the number at the end from 1 to 2.

Comment: Hi Andrius. First, thank you for taking the time to write such a considerate response. I think I should have added some clarifying information to the original question: I'm not at all uncomfortable using the terminal (and, in fact, I prefer it to installing additional packages). I am very familiar with the process of moving my home folder and adjusting lvm partitions, but I'm looking for a way to create my desired installation from the beginning inside Ubiquity. It seems ridiculous to me that this goal can be achieved in the Server install using GUI menus, but not in desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Lubuntu alternate installer .iso for 16.04.1, else you can either start from server (as you mentioned), or get mini.iso and build up from there.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04/release/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to have 2 separated encrypted partitions (root + home) as well, but no luck so far. With the GUI installer, when I choose "something else" and I create 2 LVM+LUKS partitions, I have the message "the attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 in encrypted volume has failed". If I chose the manual option setting only one LVM+LUKS, it works.

I achieved to do it by setting 1 LVM+LUKS partition and leaving free space for home partition. Then, once Ubuntu 18.04 is installed, I rerun a LiveCD to create another LVM+LUKS partition and I have to modify fstab + crypttab by end.

In this case, when I try to install Ubuntu again (to check how it would be if I had to do it), GUI installer does not recognize luks partition, so I would have to modify crypttab and fstab after installation.