# Install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with separate LVM partitions on UEFI BIOS hardware

Tags: boot, partitioning, 20.04, uefi, lvm

I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop with LVM on a laptop with UEFI BIOS. My problem is that the default installer allocates the whole disk (bar the UEFI boot partition and a swap partition) to ONE root partition. I prefer to have separate partitions for root, `/home`, `/var`, `/tmp`, etc., and no swap partition.

I have seen other attempts to solve this problem, but they either [use RAID](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299978/install-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios) or
[resizes the LVM root partition afterwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860421/desktop-install-separate-home-partition-lvm-on-luks-without-using-terminal), which is fine if you only want to migrate `/home` to its own partition, but I feel uneasy to do with, e.g., `/var`. Other attempts, e.g., [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066028/install-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios), use the server installer followed by `apt install ubuntu-desktop`, but I haven't found what server-only packages I should remove afterwards.

Is there another way to install Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and set up separate LVM partitions for root, `/home`, `/var`, `/tmp`, etc.? Or would it be safe to follow the [second](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860421/desktop-install-separate-home-partition-lvm-on-luks-without-using-terminal) route and resize the partitions afterwards? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to clean up [this RAID+LVM-solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299978/install-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-with-raid-1-and-lvm-on-machine-with-uefi-bios) to work for LVM only. The solution involves setting up the partitions manually before running the installer. The detailed instructions are found below.

### 1. Download the installer and boot into Ubuntu Live

#### 1.1 Download

- Download the Ubuntu Desktop installer from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop and put it onto a bootable media.

#### 1.2 Boot Ubuntu Live

- Boot onto the media from step 1.1.
- Select `Try Ubuntu`.
- Start a terminal by pressing Ctrl-Alt-T. The commands below should be entered in that terminal.

### 2. Partition drive and set up LVM

#### 2.0 Install ssh server

If you do not want to type all the commands below, you may want to log in via ssh and cut-and-paste the commands.

- Install

  `sudo apt install openssh-server`
- Set a password to enable external login

  `passwd`
- If you are testing this inside a virtual machine, you will probably want to forward a suitable port. Select `Settings`, `Network`, `Advanced`, `Port forwarding`, and the plus sign. Enter, e.g., `3022` as the `Host Port` and `22` as the Guest Port and press `OK`. Or from the command line of your host system (replace VMNAME with the name of your virtual machine):

  ```
  VBoxManage modifyvm VMNAME --natpf1 "ssh,tcp,,3022,,22"
  VBoxManage showvminfo VMNAME | grep 'Rule'
  ```

Now, you should be able to log onto your Ubuntu Live session from an outside computer using

```
ssh <hostname> -l ubuntu
```

or

```
ssh localhost -l ubuntu -p 3022
```

and the password you set above.

#### 2.1 Create partitions on the physical disk

- Zero the partition tables with

  ```
  sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sda
  ```
- Create two partitions; one for EFI and one for LVM.

  ```
  sudo sgdisk -n 1:0:+512M -t 1:ef00 -c 1:"EFI System" /dev/sda
  sudo sgdisk -n 2:0:0 -t 2:E6D6D379-F507-44C2-A23C-238F2A3DF928 -c 2:"Linux LVM" /dev/sda
  ```
- Create a FAT32 system for the EFI partition.

  ```
  sudo mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda1
  ```

#### 2.3 Create LVM devices

- Create a physical volume on the LVM partition

  sudo pvcreate /dev/sda2
- Create a volume group on the physical volume

  sudo vgcreate vg0 /dev/sda2
- Create logical volumes (partitions) on the new volume group. The sizes and names below are my choices. You may decide differently.

  ```
  sudo lvcreate -Z y -L 35GB --name root vg0
  sudo lvcreate -Z y -L 10GB --name tmp vg0
  sudo lvcreate -Z y -L 5GB --name var vg0
  sudo lvcreate -Z y -L 10GB --name varlib vg0
  sudo lvcreate -Z y -L 200GB --name home vg0
  ```

Now, the partitions are ready for the Ubuntu installer.

### 3. Run the installer

- Double-click on the `Install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` icon on the desktop of the new computer. (Do **NOT** start the installer via any ssh connection!)
- Answer the language and keyboard questions.
- On the `Installation type` page, select `Something else`. (**This is the important part.**) This will present you with a list of partitions called `/dev/mapper/vg0-home`, etc.
- Double-click on each partition starting with `/dev/mapper/vg0-`. Select `Use as:` `Ext4`, check the `Format the partition` box, and choose the appropriate mount point (`/` for `vg0-root`, `/home` for `vg0-home`, etc., `/var/lib` for `vg0-varlib`).
- Select the first device `/dev/sda` for the boot loader.
- Press `Install Now` and continue the installation.
- When the installation is finished, select `Continue Testing`.

**Done!**

Answer (score 0):

It's unbelievable that Ubuntu still don't offer the option to create LVM with custom partitions from the Install screen. Why would they consider jumping through this many hoops as acceptable.